# Getting sed to Replace Text With Argument

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, replace

Alright, I know this is a simple question, but I can't seem to get this sed command to work.  I'm trying to get a text file and replace one bit of it from placeholder text to a study code.  The study code that it is going to replace it with is passed into the script using arguments when the script is first ran.  The problem is, when I try to replace the placeholder text with the variable $study, it replaces it with a literally "$study".

Right now my arguments set like this:

> export study=$1
>
> export tag=$2
>
> export mode=$3
>
> export select=$4

My sed command looks like this:

> sed -i.backup -e 's/thisisthestudycodereplacethiswiththestudycode/$study/' freq.spx

Is there some easy way of getting sed to not look at the literal $study, or would it be better at this point to do it another way?

Comment: Remember that you're injecting $study into a `sed` command.  Which means it **needs** to follow `sed` semantics.  That means the delimiter (/) needs to be escaped with a backslash and several other metacharacters do too.  Do NOT make the mistake of letting 'study' be arbitrary data or this is bugged.

Comment: Yeah, this script is going to be ran from another script which is called by a web page.  Everything's going to be sanitized and checked by the time the input reaches this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Because `'` quoting prevents shell variable expansions, and `"` quoting does not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't run into this issue, but just in case...

Paul's answer is slightly suboptimal if `$study` might contain slashes or other characters with special meaning to `sed`.

```
mv freq.spx freq.spx.backup && \
    awk -v "study=$study" '{
        gsub(/thisisthestudycodereplacethiswiththestudycode/, study);
        print;
    }' freq.spx.backup > freq.spx
```

Although awkward (hah, pun!), this will always work regardless of `$study`'s contents.

Answer (score 0):

try this................... 
sed -e 's/%d/'$a'/g' amar.htm , amar.htm having the string "%d" which is indeed to be replaced and "a" is having the string to replace.