# Using command line argument to substitute a value in a .sh script

Tags: bash

New bash user here, I'm trying to accomplish something simple but can't seem to figure it out

I want to run a script (curl.sh) using a command line argument that will change every time to supply a new IP to the .sh

So running:

`~/Documents$ ./curl.sh 10.0.0.18`

Would result in the following being run:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl 10.0.0.18 blablabla
```

and then running:
 `~/Documents$ ./curl.sh 10.0.0.19`

Would change the .sh to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl 10.0.0.19 blablabla
```

I have tried setting variables with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193140/how-to-replace-bash-variable-with-command-line-arguments) article and arguments using sed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854186/getting-sed-to-replace-text-with-argument) article but must be getting the syntax wrong

Comment: You use `$1` in your script to refer to the first command line argument.  `curl $1 blahblabla`  What do you have in your script now?

Comment: "I have tried setting variables with this article and arguments using sed in this article but must be getting the syntax wrong"

Show us what you tried so someone can explain what is going wrong.

Comment: I have tried substituting the IP address in the script with $1 and then using a new IP as a command line argument but it doesn't seem to work. When I run the command in shell directly with the IP address I get an "OK" response. When I run the script (having $1 in lieu of an IP) I do not get a response

Comment: `ip="${1:-10.0.0.18}"` will use `10.0.0.18` if no arguments is provided, or it will use whatever is provided as the ip (you should validate it is an IP). Your call to curl is then `curl "$ip" blablabla`

Comment: When I run the script with a sh -x to view the command output in shell I can see the IP address is not being substituted by the command line argument, it runs literally "curl $1 blablabla"

Comment: Inside `curl.sh` you have the interpreter on the 1st line, e.g. `#!/bin/bash` and then as the next line `ip="${1:-10.0.0.18}"` and then `curl "$ip" blablabla` as the next line?

Comment: Also paste the contents of `curl.sh` into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and check for errors/warnings in your script. You should not have `"curl $1 blablabla"`, if you followed my advice. It would be `curl "$ip" blablabla"`.... Let me know if you are still stuck and **edit** and **add** your current `curl.sh` at the end of your question. Do NOT **delete** anything from your question, just **add** to it. Otherwise all the comments above will no longer make sense to visitors.